# Apply operation to multiple variables

Tags: python

I feel like this solution is overkill and I might not be using the builtins correctly.

Can someone suggest a better way to apply the same operation to a list of variables?

EDIT -- Or change them without re-assigning the values (if that's possible)

```
size = 150
free = 27
used = 123

size, free, used = list(map(lambda x: x * 1024, [size, free, used]))
```

Comment: `[i * 1024 for i in my_vars]` – the verbosity here pretty much only comes from the fact that those are individual variables, instead of a list or a dict.

Comment: You can't change `int`s: they're immutable, so you have to re-assign. But you can optimize that slightly: `size, free, used = map(lambda x: x * 1024, (size, free, used))`

Comment: What's wrong with `size = 150 * 1024; free = 27 * 1024; used = 123 * 1024`?

Comment: Ah the line afterward returns NamedTuple(size, free, used) so I just didnt want to put another 3 lines for converting from KB to Bytes if it was unneccessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "splat" unpacking to pass the items of a list or tuple to the NamedTuple constructor. Eg,

```
from collections import namedtuple

TheTuple = namedtuple('TheTuple', ('size', 'free', 'used'))

size = 150
free = 27
used = 123

t = (size, free, used)
foo = TheTuple(*[1024 * x for x in t])
print(foo)
```

**output**

```
TheTuple(size=153600, free=27648, used=125952)
```

This will even work with a generator expression:

```
foo = TheTuple(*(1024 * x for x in (size, free, used)))
```

And here's a `dict` version, using the "double-splat" operator `**`:

```
d = dict(
    size = 150, 
    free = 27, 
    used = 123
)

foo = TheTuple(**{k: 1024 * v for k, v in d.items()})
```

Answer (score 4):

I would probably use a comprehension/generator expression rather than `list`, `map` and `lambda`:

```
size, free, used = (x * 1024 for x in (size, free, used))
```

That said, if it really is advantageous to have those three names as distinct entities (rather than a single list/tuple/numpy array of items) maybe you're better off just writing it all out ...

```
size *= 1024
free *= 1024
used *= 1024
```

Comment: It is also possible to change the `[]` to `()`, so we don't create an unnecessary list (not that it even matters with only 3 elements..).

Comment: @DeepSpace -- That's true.  But it 's an list of 3 items so the memory/performance implications aren't _too_ severe and in my experience, people are more comfortable unpacking sequences than arbitrary iterables... But I guess there's not better time than now to try to shift that tide ...

Comment: the values will be wrapped up afterwards in a named tuple so it's more to do with getting a clean solution for changing the unit of measure before returning the values. The first solution will work nicely

Answer (score 1):

```
size, free, used=[x*1024 for x in [size, free, used]]
```

Comment: You might want to add a bit of commentary to explain the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply store your variables, which somehow seem like a compound, in a tuple or list like so:

```
mv = [1024, 27, 123]
```

Then, use list comprehension to apply your transformation to all of them:

```
mv = [i * 1024 for i in mv]
```

If you are using `numpy`, you can also use a `np.array` and apply the transformation on each of its elements (which it does by default):

```
mv = np.array([1024, 27, 123])
mv *= 1024
```

However, you should **definitely avoid** importing `numpy` if this is its sole use in your code.