# Changing multiple variables by the same amount

Tags: python

I was coding a problem that involved changing the coordinates of axis-aligned right triangles, as shown below.

```
x -= x1
x2 -= x1
x3 -= x1
y -= y1
y2 -= y1
y3 -= y1
```

Is there a way how I can compress variable changes such as this to one or two lines, so that it might look something like this?

```
x, x2, x3 -= x1
y, y2, y3 -= y1
```

I've been wondering about this problem because even though I only have 8 variables I have to work with, I've been thinking about the possibility where I would have to work with much more variables.

Comment: Use lists, to store multiples values that belong together

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apply operation to multiple variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38310716/apply-operation-to-multiple-variables) Similar to what you were trying - `x, x2, x3 = (a + x1 for a in (x, x2, x3))`

Comment: @EL-AJIOussama That's a syntax error...

Answer (score 0):

One way is to store everything in a list, then use a comprehension to quickly apply the same operation to each item. for example:

```
data = [1,2,3,4,5]
data = [x - 1 for x in data]
# [0,1,2,3,4]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
def f(a, *args):
    return (i + a for i in args)
a = 4
b = 5
c = 6
add = -2
a, b, c = f(add, a, b, c)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could store values in a tuple and use numpy to subtract

```
import numpy as np


x1 = 3
x2 = 9
x3 = 8

y1 = 10
y2 = 7
y3 = 5

x_coords = (x1,x2,x3)

y_coords = (y1,y2,y3)


np.subtract(x_coords,x1)


[0,6,5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to achieve sort-of what you want is to use [`numpy`](https://numpy.org/) which allows for many useful operation. In your case you would still have to "wrap" to values to another object (numpy array), however otherwise, the operatin would be quite straight-forward:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     

In [2]: data = np.array([1,2,3])                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               

In [3]: data += 5                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              

In [4]: data                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
Out[4]: array([6, 7, 8])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have so many variables that need common processing, you're probably best using dictionaries, lists, or numpy arrays instead of individual variables.

So x, x1, x2, x3 could be stored in dictionary called x and referenced as x[0], x[1], x[2], x[3].

for example:

```
x = dict()  # or [0]*4 to use a list, or numpy.zeros(4) for an array
x[0] = 10
x[1] = 5 
x[2] = 100
x[3] = 25

for key in (0,2,3): x[key] -= x[1]

print(x[0])  # 5
print(x[2])  # 95 
print(x[3])  # 20
```

If you still want to use multiple variables, you could always do this:

```
x,x2,x3 = (n-x1 for n in (x,x2,x3))
```

but, as you suspect, it is not going to make it easier or shorter.  In the end, your requirements probably call for higher dimension data structures.